# Enable SASS Source Map files for Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, source-maps

I have a Rails project, in which I use Bootstrap (SASS) gem. The map files are not generated so I cannot inspect the CSS correctly in Chrome.

I found some sass-rails-sourcemap gem but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I saw that there will be SourceMaps support with the release of the the version 4.0 of the Sprockets gem.

Therefore for the moment, you can have sourcemaps only if you compile your CSS manually using some external tool like Grunt or so.

I don't know the amount of side-effects this might have.